# Mapping of $y=2x-1$ in $z \mapsto z^2$ (complex)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Im having trouble with this question about complex mapping.

Line $y=2x-1$ (Where $y=Im(z)$ and $x=Re(z)$)
is mapped in mapping $z \mapsto z^2$.

Determine the equation of the image.

**What I have tried**
I started with
$w=f(z)=(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+2ixy=U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$
and since $y=2x-1$,

$  \begin{cases}
    U_x=x^2-(2x-1)^2       &\\
    V_x=2x(2x-1) & 
  \end{cases}$

Giving
$$U_x=x^2-\frac{V^2}{4x^2}$$
I quess im supposed to get rid of $x$, but havent managed to do it despite many efforts of manipulating the equations.. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x=-3 t^2+4 t-1 \\
 y=4 t^2-2 t \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Eliminate parameter $t$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
4 x=4(-3 t^2+4 t-1) \to 4x=-12t^2+16t-4\\
3 y=3(4 t^2-2 t) \to3y=12t^2-6t\\
\end{array}
\right.
$

add the two equation and get

$4x+3y=10t-4\to t=\dfrac{4x+3y+4}{10}$

and plug into one of the equations

$y=4 t^2-2 t \to y=4\cdot \left(\dfrac{4x+3y+4}{10}\right)^2-2\cdot \left(\dfrac{4x+3y+4}{10}\right)$

expand and simplify to get

$$16 x^2+24 x y-9 y^2+12 x+16 y-4=0$$

Which looks like a rototranslated parabola

Hope it helps

$$...$$

[image]